# Jaspersoft report preview and generated pdf differs

Tags: jasper-reports

I've a problem with the generated pdf I generate with TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio. As you can see in the image below we have spaces between every 3 digits from the right, making it easy to read.

[image: Preview image]

The pdf that we get as output do however lack these spaces, making it a lot more difficult to read. I have tried reading up on what it could be, but the Jaspersoft reports documentation is severely lacking, and I haven't been able to find anything.

[image: PDF image]

So my question is, what is causing this difference and how do I solve it?

The underlying data is a double we read from an XML, and present through a String.format where we first round it, then set it to always have 2 decimals.

Comment: What font are you using ? This might be a problem of font. See font extension in jasper.

Comment: We are using Titillium Regular, which isn't a default font. by loading the .ttf into the project.

I'll take a look into it to see if I can verify that it is the font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this seems to have been an issue with the pdf generation tool used by Tibco/Eclipse as it works fine in our production environments. Simply broken while testing through the IDE.